# Android manifest merge error related to Firebase in 2019

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

**I have this error when I try to build my app:**

> Merging Errors: Warning
>   activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode
>   was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but
>   no other declaration present app main manifest (this file), line 23

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.dm.bloggerapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Activities.HomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.RegisterActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

I think it is related to Firebase libraries I imported. In my manifest I have nothing related to android:launchMode. Any idea how can I fix this?

Thanks guys!